# Find smaller volume of solid bounded by plane and sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus

bounded by plane $x+y+z=1$ and $x^2 +y^2+z^2 = 1$.

I need this part to solve https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325143/change-of-variables-multiple-integrals-volume-question

Comment: Also is the intersection a circle or a ellipse? b/t sphere and plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a spherical cap. You know distance of the plane from centre.
$V = \frac{\pi h}{6} (3a^2 + h^2)$(Picture from Wikipedia)
How do we get this?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcLPU.png)[image: From Wiki]

Change your z axis to this. Now use Cylindrical co-ordinates
V=$\int\int\int r1d\theta d(r1)dz. $ r1 is the radius variable.

What will be the limits? 
Look at this like making the volume through discs.
It is clear that $\theta$ will change from 0 to 2$\pi$.
r1 will change with z. The limits of r1 will involve z somewhere and z will change from R(radius of sphere)-h to h.
    Check your answer with the one above mentioned.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap

Comment: I still dont understand. Could you explain more in detail? I guess we use the distance from orgin to plane and radius of sphere equal to 1 to find a by pythagorean thm?

Comment: I still dont understand how to find the limits for r and z for the integral.

Comment: I think limit for z is from (1-x-y) to (sqrt(1-v^2-w^2))

Comment: and r is from 0 to a?

Comment: How do we change z axis to the h axis?

Comment: SO i get a= root(2/3). and distance from plane to origin=1/root(3)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.1)Volume is independent of the choice of axis.(Essentially, rotating the sphere,.2)Regarding the limits- Here is a link regarding Cylindrical co-ods.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system. Now r1 which is the radial component, changes from 0 to sqrt( R^2-z^2) and z will change from R-h to h. PS Don't confuse the variables of the figure with the other variables.

Answer (score 0):

In general, $V=\pi \int_a^b[f(x)]^2dx$.
$$a^2=R^2-(R-x)^2=2Rx-x^2$$
$$V=\pi \int_0^h[a(x)]^2dx=\frac{\pi h^2}{3}(3R-h)$$.

More information can be found in [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html) location.